# Monk-Gillieson Monochromator Design Equations

Tags: resource-recommendations, spectroscopy

I'm attempting to following the meta guidelines on resource recommendations - apologies if I miss something.

I am looking for Monk-Gillieson monochromator design equations.  Basic equations are sufficient.  It would be helpful, but not required, if the resource compared and offered advice on fabrication of various spectrometer designs (gratings, prisms, etalons, etc.).

I've looked in ~10 optics textbooks including the Diffraction Grating Handbook (Palmer) without success.  Ibsen Optics has a design guide for Czerny-Turner monochromators but not the Monk-Gillieson variety.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks.